# DropzoneJS XHR sending option request

Tags: javascript, python, tornado

I am using dropzone js to upload files to server. My server is in Tornado but dropzonejs sends an Options request in the header though I set it to do method Post.

The problem is my tornado server wasn't coded to handle a Option request, only get, post and delete.

So why is dropzonejs doing this? and how do I make it do the POST directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) protocol.  If you want to accept uploads from different domains you will have to implement options() as well as post().